# Delete first match

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to find a way to delete the first match of a certain line, and not the last one.
To explain this better, here is my file:

```
(Foo Bar)
Foo = B(ar)a(foo)r
```

My problem is that I'm trying to delete the () and the text within it.
Here is my current code:

```
sed 's:(.*)::g'
```

But it outputs this:

```
Foo = Br
```

Instead of this:

```
Foo = Bar
```

How would this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` is greedy, and that will match till the last `)`.

```
sed 's:([^)]*)::g'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Gonna promote it as the answer when it will allow me.