# Remove one line only with matching string - sed

Tags: sed

I have a csv file that has a number of duplicates, I want to remove only one line (or the first line) that matches my string.

How to do this in sed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete first match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437919/delete-first-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '0,/string/{/string/d}' file
```

If you want to edit "in place" add option `-i`.

See: [How do I match only the first occurrence of a pattern?](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html)

Comment: Beware several of the solutions in the source quoted for non-GNU seds are erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n '/yourString/{:a;n;p;ba};p' file
```

An alternative:

```
sed '/yourString/{x;/./{x;b};x;h;d}' file
```